# How to update nested objects in Elasticsearch 2.2 script via Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to update a nested object in Elasticsearch via the Java API, using a technique similar to what is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360225/elastic-search-is-it-possible-to-update-nested-objects-without-updating-the-ent). The problem is how to pass the json into the script. If I just blindly concatenate the json to the script string as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363801/update-nested-field-in-an-index-of-elasticsearch-with-java-api), the Groovy does not compile. If you pass it in directly as a parameter, it just gets parsed as a string. If I try to use JsonSlurper, like:

```
String script = "ctx._source.pete = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)";
Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of("json", json);
return new Script(script, ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, params);
```

I get a compilation exception: unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurper

A further problem with the JsonSlurper approach seems to be that the Elasticsearch team has basically [disabled](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16808) it in 2.2.

Does anyone know how to pass the json in correctly via the Java API?

Comment: can you try to add `import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;` at the beginning of your script? Just to see if that compilation error gets out?

Comment: @Val Unfortunately that doesn't help, same error.

Comment: Was worth a try, though it's pretty clear why this has been disabled and why the ES folks stand firm by that decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the guys at Elasticsearch for helping me with this. The answer is to convert the JSON to a `Map` and then just pass the `Map` as a param:

```
String script = "ctx._source.pete = jsonMap";
Map<? ,?> jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of("jsonMap", jsonMap);
return new Script(script, ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, params);
```

I'm using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` to do the conversion from JSON to the `Map`.

Answer (score -1):

I have written an extensive answer on that subject on [StackOverflow in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36983040/1305969). Instead of a script, I used the `UpdateRequest` class in Java, which you have to feed with a `XContentBuilder` object containing all the changes you wish to perform.

This is a snippet of the answer:

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
//....
XContentBuilder jb = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
jb.startObject();
jb.startArray("..");

for ( /**/) {
   jb.startObject()
   .field("attrX", value)
   // ..
   .startObject("attrY")
   .field("attrZ", value)
   .endObject()
   .field("atrrW", value)
   .endObject();
}
jb.endArray();
b.endObject();
updateRequest.doc(jb);
```