# How to update nested elasticsearch value via bulkrequest?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, java-8, amazon-elasticsearch

**We are using AWS Elasticsearch - 7.7 Version**

I already followed [Update nested field in an index of ElasticSearch with Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363801/update-nested-field-in-an-index-of-elasticsearch-with-java-api)

I have below JSON Elastic Search

```
 {
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_source": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "properties": [{
            "id": 1,
            "qty": 10
        }]
    }
}
```

I have below code

```
 BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();
 request.add(new UpdateRequest(<ES Endpoint>, 1))
                        .doc(XContentType.JSON, "name", "TEST 1"));
BulkResponse bulkResponse = restClient.bulk(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

**How should I update "properties" value "qty"?**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.8/java-docs-update.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Map with all fields to update in the `doc()` call:

```
Map doc = new HashMap();
doc.put("name", "TEST 1");
doc.put("qty", 12);
request.add(new UpdateRequest("index", 1)
                    .doc(XContentType.JSON, doc));
```

Comment: I tried it gives error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of object passed must be even but was [1]`

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: We are using AWS Elasticsearch - 7.7 Version.